# RTC Jenkins - Load & Build Options

Tags: java, jenkins, ant, continuous-integration, rational-team-concert

I have a query relating to Jenkins loading : Let’s assume build has already happened for one of the repository workspace. Now the developer will make a change in specific component and give a build again.
            Is there a way in Jenkins to specifically detect only the changed component/’s to load and build  ?